# How to open KMZ file in google earth from iOS app

Tags: ios, swift, google-earth, kmz

I'm trying to open the KMZ file through google earth in my iOS application. I'm able to open the google earth application but can't open KMZ file in that application. 
The code used to open the google earth from my application is

```
    let KMZurl = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "oma", withExtension:"kmz")

    let urlstring = "comgoogleearthz://url=\(KMZurl!)"
    let Url = NSURL(string: urlstring)
    if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(Url! as URL)
    {
        UIApplication.shared.openURL(Url! as URL)

    } else {
        //redirect to safari because the user doesn't have google earth
        UIApplication.shared.openURL(NSURL(string: "https://www.google.com/earth/")! as URL)
    }
```

If any has done this, please help me. If this is not possible please let me know as well. I'm stuck on this for 2 days. I'm not able to find any documentation for this as well.
TIA

Answer (score 0):

Can we assume you're using a new 9.x version of Earth on your iOS device?  If so, that does not support loading KML/KMZ files via URL at this time. Currently the only way to get a KML/KMZ file to load is manually via Google Drive... upload your file to Drive, then go to My Places > Import KML file.

Comment: Yes I'm using version above then 9.0 to be precise its 9.2.37.7. so what you are saying that it is not possible to invoke the google earth application with KMZ file url?
So I have to download that file and save it to iCloud and then user have to manually got to the google earth and import file from iCloud and then only he can see that. Is this the only option?